# BitBucket File and folder level permissions within same repository

Tags: bitbucket

My requirement is like , i want to assign permission at file and folder level.
Let's say i have one repository name  'repository1' , under that i have two folders named  'folder1' and 'folder2'.
and on 'repository1' three uses's will work (User1 , User2 and User3) , User1 is admin. 
Is there any provision by which i can assign 'Read' permissions for 'User2' and Write permission for  'User3' on 'Folder1' and write permissions on 'Folder2' for both the users.
As currently my understanding is that Bitbucket only provides permission on repository level . Please guide on this
Thanks
Moulick Patel

Comment: For Bitbucket Server, it can be done using custom git hooks. Explained here, with examples: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy For Bitbucket Cloud, pre-receive hooks are not currently supported but there is an issue request which seems to have some voting traction: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-10471

Answer (score 1):

**No,It is not possible**. 
git is snapshot based and we can't give folder based permissions inside a repo.